# Laptop RAM upgrade: max out more than recommended?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, memory, upgrade, dell-studio

I have a Dell Studio 1735...currently with 3GB DDR2 RAM...Max RAM is 4GB.

Currently have Windows 7 32-bit installed, want to upgrade to 64-bit...

Everything on this page is compatible with this laptop, for sure...

> http://www.pcmemorystore.com/Dell-Studio_Laptops-Studio_1735-ram.htm

My question: can I make this laptop handle more RAM than 4GB, say by buying one 2GB stick, and a 4GB Stick and putting them in together?  Is it possible?

Side/harmful effects? Bad idea?  Hard on the laptop or shorten it's life?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exact question is answered in this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/73730/i-want-to-install-more-than-the-supported-amount-of-ram-on-my-pc-is-it-likely-t) and this [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/30139/what-happens-when-more-ram-is-installed-than-the-motherboard-supports). However, my suggestion is to buy two identical sticks to get the most out of it **if** you do choose to try. Meaning make sure the ram speed between them the same since it is DDR2 ram. Here is post from [Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/226933-30-possible-match-sticks-ddr2) form about mix matching ram. Here is another page with [FAQ about memory upgrade](http://computermemoryupgrade.mysuperpc.com/computer_memory_upgrade_faq.shtml).

#### Answers to your three questions

1. Side/harmful effects?

   - Side effects yes but not harmful. Worse case it will not work.
2. Bad idea?

   - Well, not the best idea unless you have money to waste if it doesn't work.
3. Hard on the laptop or shorten it's life?

   - No. Will not shorten its life.

Comment: would 4 and 4 work? that is an awful lot...

Comment: 8gigs?... No, it's will become the new standard very soon if not already.

Comment: no, my point is that my laptop maxes out at 4GB, so if i try 4 AND 4 in both ports, then i could have some problems...i don't have money to try that out lol...

Comment: @Brian Ojeda: "No" as in "no, it would not work" or as in "No, that is not an awful lot"?

Comment: Oh sorry. I miss understood the question. No as in it isn't alot. Your last question is answer here at this [question](http://superuser.com/questions/73730/i-want-to-install-more-than-the-supported-amount-of-ram-on-my-pc-is-it-likely-t) and at this [question](http://superuser.com/questions/30139/what-happens-when-more-ram-is-installed-than-the-motherboard-supports). My personal suggestion would be **not to try it.**

Comment: My answer has been reworked. Sorry about the miss understanding.