# How can I use 2x4 GB RAM on an ASUS P5K3 DELUXE?

Tags: memory

I read in [one of the posts here](https://superuser.com/questions/73730/i-want-to-install-more-than-the-supported-amount-of-ram-on-my-pc-is-it-likely-t/305703#305703) that somebody has an ASUS P5K3 DELUXE Board with 10GB RAM.
I have the same board and recently upgraded my RAM with 4x2 GB, but I'm having a very
hard time making it stable.

I've read that the P35 chipset can work only with 2GB max per DIMM slot.

I want to do the same (have 2 modules with 4GB), because 4 modules on this board causes lot of strain on the memory controller.

Which brand, model or part number do I have to use  to achieve this?